# Temperature monitor using Raspberry Pi and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a simple temperature monitor using Rails.

So far, I've managed to get a ruby script to fill a form (using Mechanize) with the data from a sensor (from the Raspberry Pi), but having to do this via a form doesn't seem right to me.

My question is this: how can I send data to a Rails application without forms?

Comment: Have you tried creating a JSON API? JSON in (via POST body) and JSON out. If you set the correct `Content-Type` header, Rails will decode this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at the whenever gem and the delayed_job gem. I use these along with sidekiq for scheduled web scraping. For reading from a sensor every 10 minutes I would just use whenever https://github.com/javan/whenever